# Understanding how the Lie algebra G2 arises in nature

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

I'm trying to understand [these notes](https://www.cimat.mx/~gil/research/rolling.pdf) on G2.  But I don't understand the very beginning.

I have no background in physics at all.  What is meant by a "configuration space?"  I looked on wikipedia but didn't understand anything.  What is meant by TQ?  What is meant by a distribution in this case?  For me, a distribution is a linear functional on some vector space of continuous complex valued functions on some manifold.

[image]

Comment: $TQ$ is the tangent space of the configuration space $Q=SO_3\times S^2$.

The meaning of "Distribution" is this context is clarified further down : "Here a distribution means a linear subbundle of the tangent bundle of a manifold." (p.5)

Comment: Asking what $TQ$ is here suggests that you might want to take a crash course in smooth manifolds before approaching this paper---which is particularly nice, by the way.

Comment: I know what a tangent bundle is, I just didn't recognize the notation.